# Add class to anchor-link on other page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a navigation set up with links to anchors on specific page.

This works when on that specific page, but how can I add the class when coming from another page on my site?

```
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".sub-menu > li > a").on("click", function(){
            $("a.active").removeClass("curlink");
            $(this).addClass("curlink");
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is usually something you do backend, not frontend.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ideas/ways to achieve this, but if you have separate file which contains navigation code then you can do one way,
you can put in a hidden element with value of `id` of the `<a>` tag of menu of navigation. So when you land on the page and found that id value from the hidden field in jquery, you can make that `<a>` of navigation activated. I mean you can apply active class to that menu.
Tell me if this is not clear, I would try to make it simple.

In simple words,

Add one hidden element in your separate pages like `<input type="hidden" value="about_us" id="nav-menu">`
And in your master page,put jquery to get this value like:
`var nav_menu = $('#nav-menu').val();` so in `nav_menu` you will have `about_us` as its value.

Now, in main master view file, you can write jquery to add active class for relevant manu like: `$('.sub-menu > li > a').removeClass('active');$('#'+nav_menu).addClass('active');`

Comment: Thank you. But yes, please please try to simplify.

Answer (score 0):

1. Simply pass one more hidden input element say with id `navigator`
2. when you are clicking on a link with id `#a1` then set this hidden element value to `"a1"`
3. Send this element with form
4. On receiver page check for value of this element say `$("#navigator").val();`
5. On the basis of the value of this, which is `"a1"` in this case, set CSS of link with id `a1` whatever you want, using `$("#a1").css();`

Answer (score 0):

Another method is that on every hyperlink add a GET parameter and receive on the receiver side and on the basis of its value set CSS.

- Let's say there are 3 links with id `a1,a2,a3`
- Add a parameter say `cameFrom` in `href` URL e.g. `href=".../*.html?cameFrom=a1"` for link `a1` and `href=".../*.html?cameFrom=a2"` for link `a2` and so on
- On receiver page get its value by using this function:

  ```
  function param(name){
     return (location.search.split(name + '=')[1] || '').split('&')[0];
  }
  ```
- Use `param(cameFrom)` and get result.
  [Link to this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39768285/8494462)